# HttpException Request is not available in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to get the `id` from a URL but I am getting this error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
private int get_id()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            int def_id = 1;
            return def_id;
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Product> get_product()
    {
        product_detail get = new product_detail();
        ProductModel db = new ProductModel();
        //List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
        int id = get.get_id();
        List<Product> product = db.get_product(id);
        return product;


    }


}
```

But when I run it, I get this error and can't get the `id` of this url: http://localhost:31621/product_detail.aspx?id=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I resolve the issue with Session State.i passed query string parameter from the page_start through Session state, to the second request and now I can get value from of `id` of url

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        Session["session_id"] = id;
    }


    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static List<Product> get_product()
    {
        product_detail get = new product_detail();
        ProductModel db = new ProductModel();
        //List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["session_id"]);
        List<Product> product = db.get_product(id);
        return product;


    }


}
```

Comment: sorry only just got your reply now - glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]))
```

Comment: thank you sir its working but i am not getting the id properly its always 0

Comment: .Current is a static property of the HttpContext class which stores the HttpContext instance that applies to the current request. You would use this in a class library referenced by your web project for example. This property can then be used to request the querystring values as required fixing the "Request not available in this context issue" posted by @Usman

Comment: Sorry have been on vacation @Yassin Hajaj